# How to hide server's IP in email header

Tags: email, header, ip, hide

I'm using a DNS service and so far I've successfully hid my server's IP address from appearing to the public (including nslookup to all my subdomains).

The only problem is that my server's IP is still showing in the email header of every sent email. Is there a way to hide it from appearing or change it to something else?

I'm using CloudFlare service, as for my email service I'm using qmail.

Comment: Hiding a mail server ip address is one of the spammer flags. Enjoy the bounces.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to hide your SMTP server?  I don't believe it's possible to hide your IP completely because the receiving server has to know where the connection is coming from for TCP/IP to work (in the same way that your browser has to know an ip address for google.com to load the page).  So the receiving server will always know the ip address even if you don't put it in a header.

There are many services that provide SMTP servers if you do not want to use your own and expose it to the world. I'd recommend exploring these options if privacy or security is a concern.

Comment: Also if this email is going to be used for "commercial" purposes I think it is illegal by the CAN-SPAM act to alter the headers.

Comment: I understand that completely but it is possible if your services pass through an external DNS service. Right now the only way to get my server's IP address is by reading the email header of the emails sent from my server.

I guess you're technically right. The only way is to use an external server for my mail service.

Thanks!

Comment: @shakabra I'm not going to use it commercially. Even if I succeeded in hiding the real server's IP, the emails are probably gonna end up in the SPAM folder for not being recognized.